# WooCommerce – wc_customer_bought_product() or $order->get_items()

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am at my wits end. I need to display certain products on customers' account pages based on their subscription. Example: If a customer subscribed to Product #517, but then switched to Product #5910, I want their emails and account page to show the data ($menu_listing) associated with #5910.

In their emails, I am able to achieve this with $order->get_items():

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_hgf_to_order');

function add_hgf_to_order( $order_id ) {
global $posts; 
global $woocommerce;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$user_id = (int)$order->user_id;
$items = $order->get_items();

   foreach ($items as $item) {

       if ( $item['product_id' ]== 517 || $item['product_id' ]== 5938 ) {
       $menu_listing = "menu_listing";

       } elseif ( $item['product_id' ]== 5910 || $item['product_id' ]== 5915 ) {
       $menu_listing = "menu_listing_c"; 

       } elseif ( $item['product_id' ]== 5934 || $item['product_id' ]== 5926 ) {
       $menu_listing = "menu_listing_a"; 
       }

   }

 return $order_id;    

}
```

While $order->get_items() works properly on the function for 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', it does not work on the customer's My Account page. Instead, I was able to call the data onto the page using wc_customer_bought_product(), however it isn't showing the customer's most recent purchase:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', 'hgf_customer_orders' );

function hgf_customer_orders() {

global $current_user;
global $posts; 
global $woocommerce;

    $email = $current_user->email;

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 517 ) || wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 5938) )  {
    $menu_listing = "menu_listing";

    } elseif ( wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 5910 ) || wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 5915) )  {
    $menu_listing = "menu_listing_c";

    } elseif ( wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 5934 ) || wc_customer_bought_product( $email, $current_user->ID, 5926) )  {
    $menu_listing = "menu_listing_a";

    } else {
    return null;
    }

}
```

What it's doing (using the example at the top), is displaying Product #517 instead of #5910. So I either need to be able to display the most recent purchase for wc_customer_bought_product() or get the $order->get_items() function to work correctly on the user's My Account page.

Anyone able to help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found a solution by pulling the code from WooCommerce > templates > my-order.php around my foreach() statement:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', 'hgf_customer_orders' );

function hgf_customer_orders() {
  wp_reset_query();

      global $posts; 
      global $woocommerce;

        $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
        ) ) );

    if ( $customer_orders ){

        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order      = wc_get_order();
            $order->populate( $customer_order );
            $items = $order->get_items();

            //      echo $order->get_order_number();

            foreach ($items as $item) {

          if ( $item['product_id' ]== 517 || $item['product_id' ]== 5938 ) {
          $menu_listing = "menu_listing";

          } elseif ( $item['product_id' ]== 5910 || $item['product_id' ]== 5915 ) {
          $menu_listing = "menu_listing_c"; 

          } elseif ( $item['product_id' ]== 5934 || $item['product_id' ]== 5926 ) {
          $menu_listing = "menu_listing_a"; 
          }

                }

        }

        } // Close for if ( $customer_orders )

        echo $menu_listing;
}
```